# How to reset the Infinite Loader in react-virtualized package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

What is the proper way to re-render the `InfiniteLoader` component that contains a `List` and `AutoSizer` component. How it works is in the parent component of our `Child.js` component, when the user clicks on a specific button in the parent component, I want the entire child component to re-render the `InfiniteLoader` which it contains. For examples, the child component, `Child.js` will contain the `InfiniteLoader` in it's `render()` method and clear all the rows, so that new data can be repopulated. Does it have something to do with clearing the cache for the InfiniteLoader beforehand? An example of the InfiniteLoader and how it's setup is shown below.

```
 state = {
    listOfResults: [],
    apiPage: 1,
    nextPageLoading: false,
  };

  cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
    defaultHeight: 200,
    fixedWidth: true,
  });

  setListRef = ref => {
    this._list = ref;
    this.registerList(ref);
  };
     render() {
       return (
        <div className='infinite-loader-container'>
          <InfiniteLoader
            isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded}
            loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
            rowCount={this.state.listOfResults.length}
            ref={ref => (this.infiniteLoaderRef = ref)}
            >
            {({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) => {
  
              this.registerList = registerChild;
  
              return (
                <div className='full-text-search-list-container'>
                  <AutoSizer>
                    {({height, width}) => {
                      return(
                        <List
                          rowHeight={this.cache.rowHeight}
                          rowCount={this.state.listOfResults.length}
                          overscanRowCount={5}
                          ref={this.setListRef}
                          deferredMeasurementCache={this.cache}
                          onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                          height={height}
                          width={width}
                          rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                        />
                      );
                    }}
                  </AutoSizer>
                </div>
              );
            }}
          </InfiniteLoader>
        </div>
       )
      }
```